# importing data from excel to word

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

given a microsoft Word invitation model, as well as an Excel sheet contain a list of peoples with them information.
the purpose is a method that's allow to search for the wanted person in the Excel list to be selected. then automatically his information be added in the Word invitation model to be printed.
here is an example:

The Word invitation model:

```
Mr: ........... born at: ......... code:........
we are honored to have you in the school tomorrow.
                                         thank you.
```

the Excel sheet

```
Num   first-name  last-name birth-date code 
1     jhon        sweeft    01-01-1994 1011
2     michal      yves      02-06-1989 1201
3     simon       mark      30-11-1973 1202
```

if we select the person with the Num 1 the Word invitation model will be as follow:

```
Mr: jhon sweeft bored at: 01-01-1994 code:1011
we are horn to have you in the school tomorrow.
                                         thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a mail merge in Word. Go to "Mailings" and then "Start Mail Merge" and then the "Step by step Mail Merge Wizard" it will take you through the entire process.

You should have saved the Excel spreadsheet, as the merge can read directly for it.